# How to detect duplicate code references in an array?

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, duplicates

I'm debugging some complex code I wrote (i.e.: I'm still writing).
At one point there is an array with code references (basically closures), populated dynamically.
There should not be any duplicates in the array, but there are!

So I'd like to add checks in the program to detect that early before several unwanted effects make it more difficult to debug (those closures manipulate data, and at the end the data is not what it should be).

For example this is what the debugger outputs:

```perl-db
  DB<0> x FORMATTERS
0  CODE(0x1f6d5e0)
   -> &Class::__ANON__[lib/Class.pm:284] in lib/Class.pm:279-284
1  CODE(0x1f6dc28)
   -> &Class::__ANON__[lib/Class.pm:284] in lib/Class.pm:279-284
2  CODE(0x1f6d5e0)
   -> REUSED_ADDRESS
3  CODE(0x1f6d5e0)
   -> REUSED_ADDRESS
4  CODE(0x1f6dc28)
   -> REUSED_ADDRESS
5  CODE(0x1f6d5e0)
   -> REUSED_ADDRESS
6  CODE(0x1f6d5e0)
   -> REUSED_ADDRESS
7  CODE(0x1f6dc28)
   -> REUSED_ADDRESS
8  CODE(0x231c800)
   -> &Class::__ANON__[lib/Class.pm:284] in lib/Class.pm:279-284
9  CODE(0x1f6d5e0)
   -> REUSED_ADDRESS
10  CODE(0x1f6dc28)
   -> REUSED_ADDRESS
```

Note that three *different* items refer to the same "lib/Class.pm:279-284", but that is OK, but those "REUSED_ADDRESS" items are not.

Obviously the debugger can detect duplicate addresses; when I tried to implement a test, my first choice would have been hashes, but you cannot really use references as hash keys.

So how would an efficient test for duplicate references in an array look like?

```perl
# sketch; untested code
my @a; # array with unknown contents
my $duplicate = 0;
for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#a; ++$i) {
    for (my $j = 0; $j <= $#a; ++$j) {
        next if ($j >= $i);
        ++$duplicate
            if ($a[$i] == $a[$j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you use the code as a hash key?

e.g.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $sub1 = sub {};
my $sub2 = sub {};
my @testarray = ($sub1, $sub2, $sub1);
my %testhash;
foreach (@testarray) {
    if (defined $testhash{$_}) {
        print "Duplicate = $_\n";
    } else {
        $testhash{$_} = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use strings for your answer when the question was specifically about (code) references?

Comment: I'm just pointing out a method to check for duplicates - how you implement it for your specific requirements is up to you!

Comment: Shorter, idiomatic: `if ( !$seen{$_}++ )`. Often used with `grep`: `my @uniq = grep !$seen{$_}++, @list;`

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I used this code to determine any duplicates in an array (a more sophisticated code could be written to indicate the actual duplicates and to count each of those):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
require 5.018_000;

use strict;
use warnings;

# return whether there are duplicates in array
sub has_duplicates(@)
{
    use integer;
    for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#_; ++$i) {
        for (my $j = 0; $j <= $#_; ++$j) {
            last if ($j >= $i);
            return 1
                if (defined $_[$i] && defined $_[$j] && $_[$i] == $_[$j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

my $sub1 = sub {};
my $sub2 = sub {};
my @array = ($sub1, $sub2, $sub1);

print "array has ", (has_duplicates(@array) ? '' : 'no '), "duplicates\n";
```

Comment: This is O(N^2). Generally speaking, this is very bad. But it probably doesn't matter here given the small number of elements you're likely to have. That said, simpler solutions exist. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: O(N^2) yes, but at most only half of it (when there are no duplicates); otherwise it uses an "early out" strategy ;-) But the operations made are all O(1). In contrast, what's the complexity for hashing and looking up a string of length *n* in a hash table of size *m*, done *o* times? *Writing a single statement (lookup/add a hash table item) does not mean it has O(1)*

Comment: Half of O(N^2) is still O(N^2). And the hash approach is O(N). The length of the string is irrelevant, just like the length of the numbers you compare are irrelevant. In technical terms, they're always going to be less than some constant, so it's a constant term. In layman's terms, we don't care what happens as the stringification and numifications of code refs grows because they will never grow. The only variable here is the size of the input list.

Answer (score 1):

Code references numify to the address of the sub, so numifications are unique.<sup>[1]</sup> Your code relies on this. But it also means we could use

```perl
use List::Util qw( uniqint );  # 1.55

@code_refs = uniqint @code_refs;
```

Similarly, we could also use less-efficient string comparisons.

```perl
use List::Util qw( uniq );  # 1.45

@code_refs = uniq @code_refs;
```

---

1. I think it's technically possible to bless code references, and thus overload their numification. I've never heard of it happening.